# passing variables in the $_GET and i have extra %% signs ... how do i get rid of them?

Tags: php, get

Here's my array:

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='" . matry::base_to('test/trace', array('patient_id' => $patient->id,'cellphone' => $patient->cellnumber)) . "'><ul class='controls'>
                <li id='check_orders'><span class='symbols'>L</span><span class='label'>Skip Trace</span></li>
                </ul></a></td>";?>
```

Should i Use :

```
$url = urldecode($url);
```

and if so how do i use that in the array?

```
index.php?q=test/trace&patient_id=ADSMAN+S01&cellphone=%28444%29444-4444

$_GET['CELLNUMBER'] = $patient->cellnumber;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see no `$_GET` in your code.

Comment: %28 and %29 correspond to the url-encoded versions of `(` and `)`. Any reason you don't want to see them? They should be encoded when used in urls.

Comment: well, he typed about only %% here

Comment: I spaced on it and added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to use Replace function to get rid of %% and following is how you do it:

1) Get your varaiable from your query string i.e `cellphone` from above question's example:

```
$myvar = $_GET['cellphone'];
```

2) Now get rid of `%` by using `str_replace` function

```
$search = "%";
$replace = "";
$subject = $myvar;

echo str_replace( $search, $replace, $subject );
```

Note: $subject can be a variable or an array

I hope it'll gonna resolve your issue.